# Very strange Javascript scoping issue

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

The following variable my_cords is undefined when it gets to the google maps function, can anyone understand why and possible give me a work around? I have defined it right at the top and set it inside a callback function, which I have seen work on global variables before..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var my_cords;
var map;

function getCareHome() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

    var address = "address here";

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            my_cords = results[0].geometry.location;

        } else {

            alert("Sorry we couldn't locate the carehome on the map: " + status);
            return false;

        }

    });



    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: my_cords,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

}

getCareHome();

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.geocode` is an asynchronous call.

Try using callbacks in the function.

For example:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        createMap(results[0].geometry.location);

    } else {

        alert("Sorry we couldn't locate the carehome on the map: " + status);
        return false;

    }

});

var createMap = function(my_cords)  {
     var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: my_cords,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend using the `var createMap = function...` form. Other than that, +1.

Comment: @ Neal: `function createMap` I'd use a function declaration, as the OP has with `getCareHome`, not a function expression.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why is my way any different? I was just showing how I create functions. I was paying no attn to the OPs declaration of functions.

Comment: @ Neal: It happens at a different time, and results in a variable referring to an anonymous function. A function *declaration* happens prior to any stepwise code executing in the scope, and results in both a binding *and* a function with a proper name. More: [*Anonymouses anonymous*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)

Comment: @Neal You make it sound painfully easy! Thanks for the crazy fast response. Learned something new.

Comment: @Jonathan no problem ^_^ Happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

geocoder.geocode is an asynchronous function. The anonymous function that sets `my_cords` won't run until some event (probably the arrival of an HTTP response) fires.

Move the code that depends on it running to inside that function.

Comment: Cheers, just pipped to the post, I upped your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Because `geocode` runs *asynchronously*, your code using `my_cords` later (setting up `myOptions`) will see the value of `my_cords` *before* the completion callback from `geocode` runs — and so `myOptions.center` will be `undefined`.

If you need `my_cords` when setting up the `myOptions`, you'll have to move that code *into* the callback on `geocode`.